# VB6 Adding a DLL reference dynamically

Tags: dll, vb6, reference, activex

I am currently making a application that has several reference DLL and i am trying to add these references on runtime. how can i make this posible in vb6?

Please help me with my problem and share me code or link for reference. i highly appreciate it. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might be wrong, but as long as the dll is registered (regsvr32), you should be able to load classes from it using the CreateObject("Class Identifier") method

Comment: is the Class Identifier is the name of the class module? Or it is the actual procedure/function name?

Comment: for example, the name of the reference is COM_MI and it has a class module named clsCOM_MI that has a procedure named ShowForm.. what would CreateObject syntax be?

Comment: something like this:  
  `dim obj  
  obj  = CreateObject("COM_MI.clsCOM_MI")  
  Call obj.ShowForm`

Comment: This "class identifier" is called a ProgID.  They are often made of two parts, Program and Component.  "Program" includes libraries (DLLs, OCXs) as well as EXEs.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678477(VS.85).aspx